# Size classes not working properly in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, xcode7, size-classes

I am working on a Universal application with all orientation support. I followed below steps

1. Selecting `width compact` & `height any` size class, see below:

[image]

> As I can understand above image describes that if we want to design layout for iPhone-4 to iPhone-6 than we should use `width compact` & `height any` size class.

While using `width compact` & `height any` class I put constraints like in the below image
[image]

2. Selecting `width compact` & `height regular` size class, see below:

[image]

> This is bit confusing for me so what I did is to consider `width compact` & `height regular` size class for iPhone-6 Plus only.

While using `width compact` & `height regular` size class I put constraints same as I put for `width compact` & `height any` size class but changed the values of constraints, see in the below image

[image]

In above image have a look at red box in right side where I have added multiple values for both `height` and `width` constraint for three size classes `width compact` & `height any`, `width compact` & `height regular`, `width regular` & `height regular`.

**My issue with size classes:** When I am running application on simulator or on device from iPhone-4 to iPhone-6 it is showing the `UIImageView` with `height` and `width` I assigned to `width compact` & `height regular` i.e. 250, where it must show `UIImageView` with `height` and `width` I assigned to `width compact` & `height any` i.e. 200.

> While running app on iPhone-6 Plus or on iPad it is showing correct `height` and `width` which I assigned for them.

**Query:** How I can achieve controller objects like UIImageView etc. in different sizes of different iPhones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iPhone models in portrait have the same trait RH-CW.
What you are trying to achieve will not work, because the the `any` will be converted into `regular`, thus regular will take precedence over `any`.

> In portrait, iPhone 6 Plus uses the compact horizontal and regular
>   vertical size classes.
>
> In portrait, iPhone 6, iPhone 5, and iPhone 4s use the compact
>   horizontal and regular vertical size classes.

Comment: I didn't get you, what is _compact horizontal_ and _regular vertical_? Did you mean _compact width_ and _regular height_?

Comment: @VijaySanghavi yes this is how they call them in HIG document https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

Comment: How one can achieve controller objects like `UIImageView` in different sizes of different iPhones? As you are saying _compact horizontal and regular vertical_ is to be used for all types of iPhone (iPhone4 to iPhone6 and iPhone6 Plus).  Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: Think relative, in proportions by using autolayout, for instance you can constraint width of the image view to be 2/3 of its super view width. Just drag using CTRL from the image view to its super view and say that they have the same width, later edit this constraint multiplier value from 1 to 2/3. Pay attention that Is Apple that is telling you that size classes are the same, not me. The quote part is from Apple documentation.

Comment: Thank you for support i'll try using that proportion idea.